# Xpath for extracting everything between two known divs

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

Is it possible to select an arbitary number of divs between two known divs as follows,

```
div[@class="foo"]
div[@id="dog"]
div[@id="cat"]
div[@id="horse"]
div[@class="bar"]
div[@class="clearall"]
div[@class="foo"]
div[@id="sheep"]
div[@id="monkey"]
div[@class="bar"]
...etc.
```

I want to select all the divs between the `div[@class="foo"]` and the `div[@class="bar"]` in each group. I don't know how many divs there will be in between, it varies.

I've tried thinking about preceeding-sibling and following-sibling but then I can only select the div 'nearest' to the known divs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. The trick here is to use the set operations from [Scrapy XSLT extensions](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-exslt-extensions).

The idea is, for each `div[@class='foo']`, select everything that comes after it minus the stuff that is after `div[@class='bar']`

Here is an example in Scrapy shell, using an HTML I created locally:

```
>>> print response.body
<div class="foo"></div>
<div id="dog"></div>
<div id="cat"></div>
<div id="horse"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="clearall"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div id="sheep"></div>
<div id="monkey"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>

>>> after_foo = "following::*[not(@class='bar')]"
>>> after_first_bar = "./following::div[@class='bar'][1]/following::*"
>>> xpath_diff = "set:difference(%s, %s)" % (after_foo, after_first_bar)
>>> for foo in response.xpath("//div[@class='foo']"):
   ...:     print foo.xpath(diff_xpath).extract()
   ...:     
[u'<div id="dog"></div>', u'<div id="cat"></div>', u'<div id="horse"></div>']
[u'<div id="sheep"></div>', u'<div id="monkey"></div>']
```